# Video-Conferencing: External mute / un-mute switch for smartphone (Samsung Note 10+)

Tags: video-camera

I'm using my smartphone (Samsung Note 10+) for online classes. I use Zoom for video-conference.
I mount the phone on a tripod and position it so that my writing desk is visible.
I then use SmartView (i.e. Miracast) to mirror my phone screen to a TV using Amazon Fire-stick. Speaker and Mic are from the smartphone only.

This setup works quite well except for the following problem -

*I frequently need to mute/unmute. The only way to do this is to reach out to the smartphone screen which is very inconvenient (it is mounted on a tripod facing down on my writing desk)*

How can I solve this? Can I buy some external mic mute/un-mute switch? Or some other hardware? Any other tips?

(I searched online for some products could not find many options. Bluetooth speakerphones from Jabra etc get very expensive for me)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably just need a better microphone with an on/off or mute/unmute button. I'd focus your searches around "vlog microphone" or "android mic mute button". Vloggers will use external mics for better sound, although very few that I've found have built-in mute buttons.

Here's I think half of what you might be looking for:
[image]
[https://www.amazon.com/Microphone-Condenser-Indicator-Gooseneck-Recording/dp/B07N2WRHMY/ref=psdc_3015406011_t3_B07WLWN2ZT](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07N2WRHMY)

Big beautiful mute button right on the base, but its input is USB, so maybe a USB to Headset adapter along with it: https://www.amazon.com/usb-headset-adapter/s?k=usb+headset+adapter

This bluetooth headset has a mute button "on the headset arm": [https://www.amazon.com/YAMAY-Bluetooth-Cancelling-Headphones-Microphone/dp/B07L13Y3K2/ref=sr_1_4?dchild=1&keywords=android+mic+mute+button&qid=1596779860&sr=8-4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07L13Y3K2)

Or you could go with a smaller earpiece perhaps: [https://www.amazon.com/TOKSEL-Bluetooth-Cancelling-Hands-Free-Compatible/dp/B0882WC8FX/ref=sr_1_8?dchild=1&keywords=android+mic+mute+button&qid=1596779860&sr=8-8](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0882WC8FX)

Or maybe this desk microphone with volume/mute controls: [https://www.amazon.com/Microphone-MAONO-Condenser-Headphone-Livestream/dp/B07SGB9329/ref=sr_1_14?dchild=1&keywords=android+mic+mute+button&qid=1596779860&sr=8-14](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07SGB9329)

Hope this helps.